Многоуровневый JSON и Python, как правильно добавить данные
есть вот такой json
{
    "log": {
        "access": "/var/log/xray/access.log",
        "error": "/var/log/xray/error.log",
        "loglevel": "info",
        "dnsLog": false,
        "maskAddress": ""
    },
    "routing": {
        "rules": [],
        "domainStrategy": "AsIs"
    },
    "inbounds": [
        {
            "port": 443,
            "protocol": "vless",
            "tag": "vless_tls",
            "settings": {
                "clients": [
                    {
                        "id": "XXXXX",
                        "email": "testuser0@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "YYYYY",
                        "email": "testuser1@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ZZZZZ",
                        "email": "testuser2@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    }
                ],
                "decryption": "none"
            },
            "streamSettings": {
                "network": "tcp",
                "security": "reality",
                "realitySettings": {
                    "show": false,
                    "dest": "www.zzzz.yy:443",
                    "xver": 0,
                    "serverNames": [
                        "www.zzzz.yy"
                    ],
                    "privateKey": "YYYYYYYYY",
                    "minClientVer": "",
                    "maxClientVer": "",
                    "maxTimeDiff": 0,
                    "shortIds": [
                        "XXXXXXXXX"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "sniffing": {
                "enabled": true,
                "destOverride": [
                    "http",
                    "tls"
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
    "outbounds": [
        {
            "protocol": "freedom",
            "tag": "direct"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "blackhole",
            "tag": "block"
        }
    ]
}

Мне нужно добавить в clients три записи для нового пользователя, делаю так
with open('~/config.json', mode='r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
        
new_record=({'settings': {'clients': [{'id': uuid, 'email': email_n, 'flow': 'xtls-rprx-vision'}]}})
        
data["inbounds"].append(new_record)
with open('~/config.json', mode='w') as file:
   json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

В итоге три значения добавляются, но не туда, куда нужно.
Как добавить информацию именно в clients ?

Записи добавляются не туда, потому что вы их не туда добавляете.
new_record={'id': uuid, 'email': email_n, 'flow': 'xtls-rprx-vision'}
data["inbounds"][0]["settings"]["clients"].append(new_record)


Дай Бог тебе здоровья, добрый ты человек!
